# Rsync wrapper to track transfers/synchronizations

Tags: linux, backup, tracking

I'm fond of rsync synchronization abilities. I want to use that on my linux machines, but I'd also want to record the state, with which storage I made synchronization and when. This is missing in rsync.

I'd like to know if there is a wrapper around rsync to store this information. Is there any other program which can save information when I run command (I can use an alias for rsync, of course).

Basically I want to pass to that program, which host to which was synchronized and when. One challenge is how to combine these log files from several hosts (I think history file should be one for them all).

Please tell me if there is any existing software (I'd really want a small wrapper around rsync rather than a big backup system), or how could I implement that (e.g. in python, but pure ideas are fine too).

What I want, detailed:

- I have several folders, I want to make backups of them from time to time (rsync works fine for that).
- I can use different hosts to store different folders. Ideally, synchronization would be non-centralized, but maybe it's not necessary.
- I want to know which folder and when was synchronized. I'd like to know whether I have more recent data on another machine or not (for me it's enough to easily get the information when data was pushed to that machine, and were there more recent pushes between other hosts).

Comment: I've found how to use graphs in python, but I thought some existing method can be used. https://www.python.org/doc/essays/graphs/

Comment: This is about logging in python. https://fangpenlin.com/posts/2012/08/26/good-logging-practice-in-python/ I'm not sure I should add these links to the post here.